# VBA How do I get a cell value as module level constant?

Tags: excel, vba, scope, namespaces

On module-level space, I can use a value as constant directly.

```
Private Const AAA As Long = 3

Sub Test()
Debug.print AAA
End Sub
```

However, I cannot use a cell value as constant.

```
Private Const BBB As Long
BBB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

Sub Test()
Debug.print BBB
End Sub
```

I want to define constant "BBB" on module-level space because this value is used on another procedure.

Please tell me a solution of this or substitute method.

Comment: Why don't you use a Public Variable instead?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to define a cell as a constant? Do you have a special reason for this? By it's nature, the cell value can change - and so isn't a constant.

You could wrap the call to read the cell in a function in a module and call it from where ever you like.

```
Public Function GetValue() as variant
    GetValue = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
End if
```

But you can also just call the line direct from your call-site.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

If you use the function wrapper way, you can set a break point when some call-site invokes the call.

As a bit of an aside, you can also define a property to read the cell and remove the write part so its read only when accessed from code. But there's nothing to stop you accessing the cell as shown above - unless you actually lock the cell with protection...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A constant needs to be assigned a value once it is declared, and I assume since a cell value can be changed, it can therefore not be used to declare a constant.

If you just want data that an end user can't manipulate you could unlock all cells, protect the workbook, and then lock the particular cell you want to use as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround like that:

```
Private Const BBB As String = "$A$1"

Sub Test()
    Dim BB As Long: BB = Range(BBB).Value
    Debug.Print BBB
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the constant to a value and then you cannot ever change it. And you cannot assign values out of the procedures or functions like this:

```
BBB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
```

About the ranges, they are variables, that must be set. A good idea, to set a constant range is to put it in a void function and to call it like this:

```
Function BBB () As Range 
    Set BBB = Worksheets("ale").Range("aleale") 
End Function 

Public sub aaa
    dim my_value
    my_value = BBB
    debug.print (my_value)
End sub
```

Thus, it is like a constant, but not exactly and yet it is suitable for your ideas.